# Three.js' CSS3D official Panorama demo not working in IE 10+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, three.js, internet-explorer-11

I have been using the CSS3D Renderer by Three.js to render interactive Cube Maps, which are a bit like the old QTVR environment.
This all works great and super fluent in most browsers and even tablets. But I found that it doesn't work in IE10, IE11, while they do support CSS3D.

The demo by Three.js themselves is at http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_panorama.html.
Though all other CSS3D demos seem to work in IE, this one does not, sometimes there's some strange blinking. And I'm at a loss as to why. I have been searching for limitations in plane and texture sizes, but not a clue.

Can anyone tell me what's going on or even better, get this demo to work on IE?

PS1: It's not that I'm an IE fanboy, but the project is an educational game and many schools have IE.
PS2: Yes, I could also file bug report with Three.js, and I will, but I'm sure the Stackoverlfow community is faster.

Comment: I am seeing intermittent "flashing" in Chrome on OSX. It appears that the sides of the skybox are (at times) not positioned properly, and they overlap by 10% or so, causing z-buffering-like problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've noticed the edges sometimes show a black line in Chrome. But that's not the problem I'm talking about. In IE10 for example, the screen just stays black, while the other CSS3D demos, like http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html work just fine.

Comment: It is not just a black line at the edges of the skybox in Chrome that I see. It is 10% overlap of the two faces that meet at the edge -- and, it is intermittent. Yes, I understand the post is about IE -- just trying to determine if the browser is the real issue.

Comment: There's some intentional overlap to prevent gaps between the faces. For me, my adaptation on OSX in Chrome, Firefox, Safari is working absolutelt fluently, also on iPad. So I have no concerns about these browsers.

Comment: 1. I am not referring to the 2 pixel overlap. Snapshot: http://imgur.com/FVE9mwG. I see flashing/flickering at the 10% overlap between skybox sides, and the overlap is intermittent. 2. Sorry I can't help you with IE, but you may get more help if you describe in detail what you mean by "it doesn't work" and there is "some strange blinking".

Comment: I'm suspecting the lack of support for "transform-style: preserve-3d", which affects nested 3D elements. I'll post any progress here. http://bit.ly/1eWrk9c

Comment: Have a look at this PR, which was never merged: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3161 and this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4098

Comment: That's amazing. I was just digging through the Three.JS issues on Github a minute ago and ran into your name there, issue 4098 (and 3161) :-) I will have a look at that pull request.